# Distributed training of tf.learn Estimators?

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, computer-vision, distributed-computing

I want to train a Convolutional Neural Network on MNIST in a distributed way, using Tensorflow high-level apis. 
I tried to specify a cluster configuration, and pass it to an Estimator (code below).

I am getting the following error 
**Parameter to MergeFrom() must be instance of same class: expected tensorflow.ConfigProto got property**

Does anyone know what's wrong in how I am specifying the configuration?

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from __future__ import division
from __future__ import print_function


import grpc
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.contrib import learn
from tensorflow.contrib.learn.python.learn.estimators import  model_fn as model_fn_lib
from tensorflow.contrib.learn.python.learn.estimators import run_config as run_config_lib
from tensorflow.python import debug as tf_debug
tf.logging.set_verbosity(tf.logging.ERROR)
import json
import os
import shutil

### Data - Mnist

mnist=learn.datasets.load_dataset('mnist')
train_data=mnist.train.images
train_labels=np.asarray(mnist.train.labels, dtype=np.int32)
eval_data=mnist.test.images
eval_labels=np.asarray(mnist.test.labels, dtype=np.int32)

BATCH_SIZE=100
NUM_EPOCHS=10
train_input_fn = learn.io.numpy_input_fn({'x': train_data}, train_labels, shuffle=True, batch_size=BATCH_SIZE, 
                                         num_epochs=NUM_EPOCHS)
batch_size = 100
num_epochs = 1
eval_input_fn = learn.io.numpy_input_fn({'x': eval_data}, eval_labels, shuffle=False, batch_size=batch_size, num_epochs=num_epochs) 

### Cluster

my_cluster = {'ps': ['/cpu:0'],
                 'worker': ['/gpu:0']}
os.environ['TF_CONFIG'] = json.dumps(
          {'cluster': my_cluster,
           'task': {'type': 'worker', 'index': 1}})

my_configs=learn.RunConfig()

server = tf.train.Server(server_or_cluster_def=my_configs.cluster_spec, job_name='worker')

### Model

def cnn_model_fn(features, labels, mode):

    input_layer=tf.reshape(features['x'],shape=[-1,28,28,1])

    #conv1
    conv1=tf.layers.conv2d(inputs=input_layer,
                           filters=32,
                           kernel_size=[5, 5],
                           padding='same',
                           activation=tf.nn.relu)
    pool1=tf.layers.max_pooling2d(inputs=conv1, pool_size=[2,2], strides=2)

    #conv2
    conv2=tf.layers.conv2d(inputs=pool1,
                           filters=64,
                           kernel_size=[5,5],
                           padding='same',
                           activation=tf.nn.relu)
    pool2=tf.layers.max_pooling2d(inputs=conv2, pool_size=[2,2], strides=2)

    #fully connected layers
    pool2_flat=tf.reshape(pool2, [-1, 7*7*64])
    dense1=tf.layers.dense(pool2_flat, 1024, activation=tf.nn.relu)
    dropout = tf.layers.dropout(inputs=dense1, rate=0.4, training=mode == learn.ModeKeys.TRAIN)

    #fc2
    logits=tf.layers.dense(dropout, 10, activation=tf.nn.relu)
    loss = None
    train_op = None

    #loss
    if mode != learn.ModeKeys.INFER:
        onehot_labels=tf.one_hot(indices=tf.cast(labels, tf.int32),depth=10)
        loss=tf.losses.softmax_cross_entropy(onehot_labels=onehot_labels, logits=logits)

    #optimizer
    if mode == learn.ModeKeys.TRAIN:
        with tf.device("/job:worker/task:1"):
            train_op = tf.contrib.layers.optimize_loss(
            loss=loss,
            global_step=tf.contrib.framework.get_global_step(),
            learning_rate=0.0001,
            optimizer="Adam")

    #predictions
    predictions={
            'classes': tf.argmax(logits, axis=1) ,
            'predictions': tf.nn.softmax(logits,name="softmax_tensor")           
        }
    return model_fn_lib.ModelFnOps(mode=mode, predictions=predictions, loss=loss, train_op=train_op)

classifier=learn.Estimator(model_fn=cnn_model_fn, model_dir="/tmp/mnist_distributed", config=my_configs)

### logging

tensors_to_log = {"probabilities": "softmax_tensor"}
logging_hook = tf.train.LoggingTensorHook(tensors=tensors_to_log, every_n_iter=50)

### Metrics

metrics = {
  "accuracy":
      learn.MetricSpec(
          metric_fn=tf.metrics.accuracy, prediction_key="classes"),
}

### Distributing training

distributed_experiment=learn.Experiment(estimator=classifier, 
                train_input_fn=train_input_fn,
                eval_input_fn=eval_input_fn,
                eval_metrics=metrics,
                #train_monitors=my_monitors,
                train_steps=200,
                )

distributed_experiment.train_and_evaluate()
```

Answer (score 1):

If u want to run a distributed estimator in TF, there is an instance:

```
from tensorflow.contrib.learn.python.learn import learn_runner
from tensorflow.contrib.learn.python.learn.estimators import run_config

...

learn_runner.run(
  experiment_fn=create_experiment_fn(config),
  output_dir=output_dir)
```

And the 'experiment_fn' here is just the 'distributed_experiment' in your code. There is also should be an 'output_dir' in your experiment

Answer (score 0):

my_config should be an instance of RunConfig instead of RunConfig itself. When RunConfig init it will load the ps, workers and task config from TF_CONFIG environment variable.
https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/learn/RunConfig

Comment: Class instantiation fixed. Thanks, I am now able to start a server, but the above code still halts when I run 
    distributed_experiment.train()
Do you see anything else I might be missing?

Comment: @smh Could you provide any logs? Do you not have 1 ps and 1 worker?

Comment: Do I need to start a different server as a ps?
I am ill-defining the cluster, or the way training gets distributed in the cnn_model_fn, but haven't figured out how to fix it. 
These are the logs I get before **distributed_experiment.train()** halts:
    `DEBUG:tensorflow:Setting feature info to {'x': TensorSignature(dtype=tf.float32, shape=TensorShape([Dimension(None), Dimension(784)]), is_sparse=False)}.
    DEBUG:tensorflow:Setting labels info to TensorSignature(dtype=tf.int32, shape=TensorShape([Dimension(None)]), is_sparse=False)
    INFO:tensorflow:Create CheckpointSaverHook.`

Comment: You should create two different process one as ps and another as worker. ps process just use server.join() while the worker do the experiment. Distributed tensorflow ref:http://ischlag.github.io/2016/06/12/async-distributed-tensorflow/